# Unable to mount NFS shares on Windows clients

Tags: windows, chef-infra, nfs

I have an NFS share set up on a Linux box. I have my recipe installing the NFS services for Windows and I am able to connect to the NFS share using the UNC path or mapping the drive. I can manually mount the share as well, using either mount or net use successfully. I'm trying to automate this with Chef but the same commands that work manually are not working when I Chef it. I've tried multiple methods and none have worked.

```
mount "X:" do
    device "\\\\d-devfs02.domain.com\\software"
    action :mount
end
```

ArgumentError: The network path was not found.

```
mount "X:" do
    device "d-devfs02.domain.com:/software"
    fstype "nfs"
    action :mount
end
```

ArgumentError: The parameter is incorrect.

```
execute "Mount" do
  command "net use X: \\\\d-devfs02.domain.com\\software"
  action :run
end
```

---- Begin output of net use X: \d-devfs02.domain.com\software ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
---- End output of net use X: \d-devfs02.domain.com\software ----
Ran net use X: \d-devfs02.domain.com\software returned 2

```
execute "Mount" do
  command "C:/Windows/System32/mount.exe \\\\d-devfs02.domain.com\\software *"
  action :run
end
```

---- Begin output of C:/Windows/System32/mount.exe \d-devfs02.domain.com\so
ftware * ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: 'C:/Windows/System32/mount.exe' is not recognized as an internal or exte
rnal command,
operable program or batch file.
---- End output of C:/Windows/System32/mount.exe \d-devfs02.domain.com\soft
ware * ----
Ran C:/Windows/System32/mount.exe \d-devfs02.domain.com\software * returned
 1

**This one just blows my mind. Not only have I confirmed that the file exists in that location, this command (along with all the net use commands) work when I run them manually.**

Net use and mount commands work when I do them manually. I'm running chef-client as myself so it is not a permissions problem. Chef-client cannot see mount.exe for some reason and net use has an issue with the path. I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: The first code snippet should work. It is even shown in documentation http://docs.opscode.com/resource_mount.html. Do you run chef with the same user as you run commands manually? May be Chef does not have some permissions to access the share?

Comment: I'm running chef-client as myself and I am able to connect to the share when I run the command manually. I'm wondering if there is some change in the context of chef-client run that would break this? Or maybe something needs to change if its an NFS share on a Windows client?

Comment: I would recommend asking on the Chef mailing list chef@lists.opscode.com and see if anyone else has experienced the same issue. You could also try opening a ticket at tickets.opscode.com, since this seems like a bug.

Comment: Even 7 years later, I'm running into the same problem. None of this stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a 64-bit Windows machine? This could be because the Ruby in Chef is a 32-bit Ruby, and so Windows' helpful "filesystem redirector" kicks in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx

In other words, the actual path as seen by the 32-bit Ruby is C:\Windows\Sysnative, not C:\Windows\System32.